# Translate model's plural form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have got a model, that is called vehicle.

In my translation the model must be:
  vehicle => Fahrzeug
  vehicles => Fahrzeuge

I tried to set this in the locales file, but it did not work:

```
  activerecord:
    models:
      vehicle: Fahrzeug
      vehicles: Fahrzeuge
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ActiveRecord first translates the model name using I18n.translate with default

```
:count => 1
```

Pluralizing this string afterwards dosn't know about model translations.

But, human accepts options so

```
Vehicle.model_name.human(:count => 2)
```

does the trick together with pluralized translations:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      vehicle:
        one: 'Fahrzeug'
        other: 'Fahrzeuge'
```

Comment: Since different languages have different plural rules, a look at [this table](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) might be interesting.

Comment: so what would arabian poeple use in the header of an index? `few` or `many`? I don't know. But of cause you can use `:count=>8` for `few` or `:count => 70` for many. If you know the amount, you can pass it to `human`.

Comment: There should be a version that's more pleasant to the eye

Answer (score 0):

you are just one step away: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization

```
 activerecord:
    models:
      vehicle:
        one: Fahrzeug
        many: Fahrzeuge
```

in rails 4 this seems to be changed from `many` to `other`

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user:
        one: Dude
        other: Dudes
```

Comment: somehow it does still translate vehicles to "Fahrzeugs"

Comment: the only other thing that i can think of is the "inflections.rb" file, but i don't think that it would help...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `other` instead of `many`? That worked for me at least. I am on Rails 3.2.3.