# pluralize and i18n in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

For my Ruby on Rails (7) app, I have locale yaml definitions of this form:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      author:
        one: AutorIn
        other: AutorInnen
```

But when I use something like

```
pluralize(10, Author.model_name.human)
```

the function doesn't take the correct plural form - it should say "10 AutorInnen", but it says "10 Autors"?

Comment: Ensure that current locale is `de`

Comment: It is...otherwise it would say "10 authors" (note the "h" in the word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use count instead of pluralize? This is what seems to have worked for these similar questions:

- [override default pluralize for model-name in rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178900/override-default-pluralize-for-model-name-in-rails3/6179686#6179686)
- [Translate model's plural form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316467/translate-models-plural-form)